# How to add smooth page transitions when using meteor and react?

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I just want to add smooth transitions between pages. I'm using `Meteor`, `React` and `FlowRouter`. I tried to add several jquery plugins but it does not work. How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html

Comment: Great stuff. Could you please tell me if I am able to use jquery with add-on components?